# Installing client certificate on android programmatically without dialog?

Tags: android, certificate, client-certificates

I'm trying to install client certificate on android programmatically, using the following code :

```
Intent clientCertInstall = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
clientCertInstall.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_PKCS12, clientCert);
clientCertInstall.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME, "Client Cert");
MyActivity.this.startActivityForResult(clientCertInstall, REGISTER_CLIENT_CERT);
```

When the installation activity launches, android requests the user to enter password for the certificate (although there is no password and just clicking ok works)

[image]

More over, after clicking OK the user is requested by android to enter a name for the certificate, although i gave him a name in the "KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME" parameter.

[image]

This behavior annoys my users, they don't understand about certificates and just want it to be installed automatically without dialogs, how can i achieve this ? avoiding even one dialog would be very helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This is ["by design"](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/unifying-key-store-access-in-ics.html). Allowing apps to install certificates without user approval would open up the possibility of man-in-the-middle attacks on SSL-secured communication channels, such as online banking. That said, the dialog tells you none of this and users would undoubtably press OK regardless of what it said.