# Install CA Certificates programmatically in android for VPN

Tags: android

How do I silently install CA Certificates as a device owner, the installCACert method does not allow me to use the certificate for the VPN profile

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484191/installing-client-certificate-on-android-programmatically-without-dialog